# 'is to be' vs 'was to be' with present perfect at the end of the sentence [future seen from the past]

Tags: future-constructions, future-in-the-past

*DNA testing **was to be used** by police in the search for the missing Dublin schoolboy. His parents have welcomed the news.*

Why 'was to be used' is **incorrect** in this sentence and '**is to be used' is suggested** as correct by the 'Advanced Grammar in Use' book?
Which part of this sentence suggests that we have '*The future from now*' instead of '*The future seen from the past*' scenario?
I thought that 'was to be' is correct as I wasn't sure whether the search took place in the past or will take place in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one could be correct, given a fitting context.

However, the second sentence, with the verb "have welcomed", sets a time frame extending up to the present. That means only "is to be used", referring to future use of DNA, is correct.

If the sentence used a perspective in the past about future use of DNA, then "was to be used" might fit.

Answer (score 2):

The next sentence - *His parents have welcomed the news.* - indicates that the announcement about using DNA testing has only recently been made, so the testing is in 'the future from now'.